# Can't find Main class in Jar in Kotlin application build with gradle

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, jar, kotlin

I have a javaFx Kotlin application build with gradle.
It's a file containing main method:

```
package com.grined.toptal.invoice

import javafx.application.Application

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Application.launch(App::class.java)
}
```

Gradle file looks like that:

```
version = '1.4'


buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.41'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = "com.grined.toptal.invoice.MainKt"

jar {
    zip64 = true
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "$mainClassName"
    }

    from {
        configurations.runtime.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile "org.mapdb:mapdb:3.0.5"
    ...
}
...
```

I'm calling `gradle clean build` to produce a jar.

When I'm trying to call `java -jar jarName.jar` I see that error:

`Error: Could not find or load main class com.grined.toptal.invoice.MainKt`

I tried to use `Main` instead of `MainKt`, the same issue. Also, I checked content of jar file and there is a necessary file in a required place.

Comment: Does `gradle run` work?

Comment: Yes, it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with dependency `org.mapdb:mapdb:3.0.5`. Removing it - solves the problem.

Comment: I have a similar issue. After removing a dependency, it now works. 
Did you find a way to keep using the dependency and make it work. This issue is very weird.